# How to change the colors of the outliers in matlab boxplot?

Tags: matlab, statistics, data-science, boxplot

I'm dealing with matlab boxplot and I want to change the colors of the outliers. I tired somethig like this without success:

```
figure
hold on
A=boxplot(Data,Gr,'labels',Labels,'colors',RGB,'notch','on');


grid on
ylabel('Length','Interpreter','latex','FontSize',25)
ax=gca;
ax.XTick = [1 : 44]; 
ax.XTickLabels=Labels
ax.XTickLabelRotation = angle;
ax.TickLabelInterpreter= 'Latex';

h = findobj(gcf,'tag','Outlier')

for i = 1:numel(h)
if rem(i,2)==0
    h(i).MarkerEdgeColor = green;

end
end
```

Therefore i rilied on findobj function. Data is an array of different vectors each one containing several numbers. Gr groups each one of these while Label contain several names. RGB is an 22x3 array (one color for each variable). It returns me always red outliers. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please post some (short) code that we can run as is; that is, define all variables. And explain why it doesn't do what you want

Comment: If I knew why it doesn't do what I want I would have not asked. Anyway the part of the box plot is good but I cannot succeed in changing the colors of the outliers.

Comment: By "why" I meant the symptoms, not the cause

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve my problem. The tag is wrong : I changed  'Outlier' with 'Outliers' and the code runs. Thank you anyway

#Edit 01/10/2020

I want to share with the community a part of a recent experience that I found to be useful in order to add some tips that could help Matlab users:

Basically I wanted to colour differently the boxplots and their outliers.

The result is reported in the image

[image]

```
angle=315;

Random = randn(5,5);

Data = [Random(1,1:end) Random(2,1:end) Random(3,1:end) Random(4,1:end) 
Random(5,1:end)];

Gr = [zeros(size(Random(1,1:end))) ones(size(Random(1,1:end)))... 
2*ones(size(Random(1,1:end))) 3*ones(size(Random(1,1:end)))... 
4*ones(size(Random(1,1:end)))];

RGB = [rgb('DeepskyBlue') ; rgb('MediumSpringGreen') ; rgb('DeepSkyBlue'); 
rgb('MediumSpringGreen'); rgb('DeepSkyBlue')];

Labels = 
 {'$Label_{1}$','$Label_{2}$','$Label_{3}$','$Label_{4}$','$Label_{5}$'}


figure
hold on
B=boxplot(Data,Gr,'labels',Labels,'colors',RGB,'notch','on');

ylabel('$Your Data$','Interpreter','latex','FontSize',25)
bx = gca;
bx.XTick = [1 : 5]; 
bx.XTickLabels=Labels;
bx.XTickLabelRotation = angle;
bx.TickLabelInterpreter= 'Latex';

 n = findobj(gcf,'tag','Outliers')

 for j = 1:numel(n)
   if rem(n(j).XData(1),2)~=0
       n(j).MarkerEdgeColor = rgb('DeepSkyBlue');
        else
    n(j).MarkerEdgeColor = rgb('MediumSpringGreen');
 end
```

end

The rgb function can be found in mathworks. Basically the idea is to find and recolour boxplot's odd and even  positioned outliers with the same colour of the boxplot. I hope you find it useful to your purposes.